# Vertically offset tick labels in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want tick labels to be placed above the tick instead of centered on the tick.

This is how it looks now:
[image: This is how it looks now:]

This is how I want it to look:
[image: This is how I want it to look:]

I've read about tick label formatting [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) but I could only figure out how modify horizontal padding. I think I need to modify vertical padding. Does anyone have an idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the vertical alignment of the tick labels directly to shift them up.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(100,)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax[0].plot(data)
ax[0].set_title("No shift")
ax[1].plot(data)
for tick in ax[1].get_yticklabels():
    tick.set_verticalalignment("bottom")
ax[1].set_title("With shift")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

You can see that in the first subplot the labels are centered on the ticks, while on the bottom plot they are above it.

[image]